# linux kernel debug through 1394 port

Tags: debugging, kernel, firewire

I have my linux kernel installed in one machine which is having ieee1394A  pci card inserted.

I want to see the kernel boot messages in the windows  host ...Windows7 is installed in my laptop having the ieee1394 firewire port.

Is it possible ? If so please let me know the procedure...

Thanks in Advance
Deepthi